# Is a bandlimited function smooth?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Definition of [**smoothness**](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Smoothness)

Definition of [**bandlimited**](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bandlimiting): for simplicity, let's consider a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is bandlimited if the support of its Fourier transform lies in $[\Omega, \Omega]$ for some $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}$

Specifically, how smooth is this function given that I know it's bandlimited? $$Sinc(4\pi t)$$

Comment: The sinc function is $C^{\infty}$. There's a general principle that smoothness on one side corresponds to decay on the other, and band-limited functions have pretty nice decay.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true that the Fourier transform of a compactly supported function is smooth. There is a [cute proof using the fact that the Fourier transform is actually analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem). (Refer to the "Holomorphic Fourier transform" section.) A more direct proof (perhaps simpler) can be constructed using the general ideal that the Fourier transform trades off smoothness and decay. See Remark 9.3(a) in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, for example, but the idea is probably worked out more explicitly elsewhere.

In fact, more is true. Supposing the compactly supported function is smooth, its Fourier transform [decays very rapidly and lies in the Schwarz space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/382124/284566). Also, [this result extends to distributions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195681/fourier-transform-of-compactly-supported-distribution-is-smooth).