# Estimate derivatives in terms of derivatives of the Fourier transform.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let us suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function. Furthermore, for every $\alpha$ multi-index, there exists $C_\alpha > 0$ such that 
$$
|D^\alpha f(\xi)| \leq \frac{C_\alpha}{(1+|\xi|)^{|\alpha|}}.
$$
Does it follow that, for every $\alpha$, there exists $C'_\alpha > 0$ such that
$$
|D^\alpha (\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f))(x)| \leq \frac{C'_\alpha}{|x|^{n+|\alpha|}}
$$
where $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse Fourier transform (which exists since $f \in \mathcal{S}'$)?
I tried to do it using the definition, but it is really messed up because $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is in general in $\mathcal{S}'$. For instance, if $f$ is a constant function, then its inverse transform is a dirac $\delta$, then I should give it a pointwise meaning, and I don't know when this is possible. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187326/how-to-prove-a-function-is-the-fourier-transform-of-another-l1-function). Are you considering Schwartz class?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal: $f$ is smooth and bounded, so $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)$ is in the space of tempered distributions $\mathcal{S}'$. I cannot say anything more though, since it might be something like a $\delta$. Random thoughts: if $f$ is compactly supported, $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is automatically smooth, but then bounding the derivatives of $f$ is no longer necessary. Also, I would like to understand whether if there is an approximation approach: i.e. you approximate something in $\mathcal{S}'$ by smooth (also $L^1$'d be enough) functions, and then take the limit in $\mathcal{S}'$-norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://yannisparissis.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/littlewood-paley-inequalities-and-multipliers/) settles it. See Theorem 9, it also settles regularity issues.