# Conditions for the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function to be in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I know that if one needs to use the Fourier inversion formula, one condition is to make sure the function $f$ and its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ both lie in $L^1$. If now I have a function $f$ which lies in both $L^1$ and $L^2$, what kind of additional conditions can make its Fourier transform also lies in $L^1$? Thank you!

Comment: You may want to consider [Schwartz class](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187326/how-to-prove-a-function-is-the-fourier-transform-of-another-l1-function).

Comment: The Fourier transform of $f \in L^1$ is uniformly continuous so the issue is decay. Typically, the smoother $f$ is, the faster its Fourier transform decays.

Answer (score 4):

If $f\in C^{n+1}(\mathbb R^{n})$ and $\partial^{\alpha}f\in L^{1}\bigcap C_{0}$ for $|\alpha |\leq n+1$, then $\mid \hat{f}(\xi) \mid \leq C (1+ \mid \xi \mid)^{-n-1}$ and hence $\hat{f} \in L^{1}(\mathbb R^{n})$. [For the proof you may see, Real Analysis by G. B. Folland, Chapter 8]

Comment: What do you mean with $C_0$? Decay at infinity or compact support?

Comment: @Inquisitive On what page?

Comment: It's comes from the Theorem 8.22e in G.B. Folland, Real Analysis Vol. 1 Modern Techniques and Their Applications, 2013. See also the comment in the begining of Section 8.4.

Answer (score 1):

From [Suppose that $f \in L^1 $ and $\hat{f} \geq 0$. If $f$ is continuous in $0$ then $\hat{f} \in L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538495/suppose-that-f-in-l1-and-hatf-geq-0-if-f-is-continuous-in-0-then), another sufficient condition is that

> [$f\in L^1, \hat f \geq 0$ and $f$ is continuous at $0$] $\implies \hat f \in L^1$.

Although the proof provided is about $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, it seems that due to nice properties of the Gaussian (e.g. [Fourier transform on $\mathbb R^n$ of Gaussian function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565928/fourier-transform-on-mathbb-rn-of-gaussian-function)) the same is true for $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$.

EDIT: I just learned from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/712635/405572) that Bernstein gave another sufficient condition

> [$f\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ and $\alpha$-Holder continuous for $\alpha>\frac 12$] $\implies \hat f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.